# How to keep digit and special character in preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to replace {goal} braces with a price such as $45. for example

```
 $pattern = /\{goal\}/

 $replacement = $45.00

 $subject = Final price is {goal}
```

so the function looks like

```
 preg_replace('/\\{goal\\}/', '$45.00', 'Free shipping for all orders over {goal}');
```

Actual output should be

```
Final price is $45.00
```

But I'm getting the output as

```
 Final price is .00
```

So it seems preg_replace replacing the whole digit and the special character with a blank string. Is there any solution to keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `$n` will be replaced by the text captured by the `n'th` parenthesized pattern. [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-parameters)

When you used `'$45.00'` php consider it as 45th captured group. So you should escape `$` by `\` to solving problem

```
preg_replace('/\{goal\}/', '\$45.00', 'Free shipping for all orders over {goal}');
```